# Cursor clickable icon appear when mouse over event happened

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following implementation. When user clicks on the y axis title label, then message pop up.

However, there is no indication for the first time user that shows y axis label clickable. Therefore I would like to know how to implement cursor clickable icon (hand icon) when mouse over the y axis title label.

```
$(document).on("click", '#chart text[fill="rgba(60,60,60, 0.9995)"]', function(){
    var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
    $("#chart").css("cursor", "pointer");
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/AGOMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this below your click handler:

```
 $(document).on("mouseover", '#chart text[fill="rgba(60,60,60, 0.9995)"]', function(){
          $('#chart text[fill="rgba(60,60,60, 0.9995)"]').css("cursor", "pointer");
        });
```